# Magento Apply Tax on Original Product price instead of discounted price

Tags: ee-1.12.0.2

Using Magento Enterprice ver. 1.12.0.0

Prices are coming including Tax.
I want the Tax to be calculated on the original product price instead of the discounted price ( in case of catalog price rules)
For example:

```
Original Product Price ( including Tax) : $110
Catalog price rule discount: 40%
Tax : 10%
```

Currently the Tax is being calculated on the discounted price, so the final price of the product after Discount and tax is:

```
$110 - (40% Discount on $110) = $66
```

(So tax is calculated like 10% of discount price)

But what I want is, if a catalog price rule is applied to a product , Tax should be calculated on the original price of the product , and not the discounted price. So it should be like:

```
$100  + (10% Tax on $100) - (40% of $100) = $70
```

*Note: Prices are coming including Taxes*

Answer (score 0):

You can change that Configuration as below : **System > Configuration > Tax > Calculation Settings**  , than change Configuration for according to your needs for **Catalog Prices** & **Apply Discount On Prices**....

[image]

Comment: Already applied above settings.This option is only effecting shopping cart price rules.
Catalog price rules are not affected by this option.

Comment: @MohdQasim if you have less products & orders, can you reindex once by sytem > Index Management.....

Comment: Already done indexing several times